# Delete link not working phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've used Phoenix's built in gen.HTML to generate a simple view but it's not working

```
<%= link "Delete", to: event_path(@conn, :delete, event), method: :delete, data: [confirm: "Are you sure?"], class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs" %>
```

And on the page it looks like it suppose to but it just append # to address

Generated structure:

```
<form action="/event/1" class="link" method="post">
   <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete">
   <input name="_csrf_token" type="hidden" value="BwUSGQcDO1MwPzw0HBgqLnshHn8HNgAAnCTjuMt0viFshobX4XM/dQ==">
   <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-submit="parent" href="#">Delete</a>
</form>
```

Am i missing a js import of sort?
I can also this being downloaded by the browser:

```
//This is being downloaded as phoenix_html.js
// Although ^=parent is not technically correct,
// we need to use it in order to get IE8 support.
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-submit^=parent]')
var len = elements.length

for (var i=0; i<len; ++i) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
    var message = this.getAttribute("data-confirm")
    if(message === null || confirm(message)){
      this.parentNode.submit()
    };
    event.preventDefault()
    return false
  }, false)
}
```

Comment: Did you `import App.Router.Helpers` and `alias App.Endpoint` in your view?

Comment: No.. But it didn't help

Comment: I believe you changed `App` to your real application name, right? This also could be helpful: http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/routing#section-more-on-path-helpers

Comment: BTW, would you try to just `IO.puts` `event` and `event_path(@conn, :delete, event)` from inside your view?

Comment: The page is not being reloaded, the # is just being appended to address. Action in controller is never being called. It's client's side issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: This happens to be known issue. Here is the fix:

```
In brunch-config.js
autoRequire: {
  "js\\app.js": ["web/static/js/app"]
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/1319)

Comment: Hm. I've come upon the same problem (much later, hi from the future!), but shouldn't the `endpoint.ex` that allows `js` at `/` fix it? Or is that the known issue?

Comment: @kiminoa That was known issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue was anyone able to fix this

Answer (score 9):

For anyone else hitting this I had a completely different problem that manifested itself in the same way, will drop this here in case it helps:

It turns out I accidentally deleted `import "phoenix_html"` from the app.js file mistaking it for being part of the generated boilerplate, adding it back fixed my issue.

Comment: Thanks you for that.

Answer (score 8):

While not the particular solution to OP's issue, this error can also arise if you place

`<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>`

in the the wrong place in `app.html.eex`. (For example inside `<head>` instead of at the end of the body)

Comment: I changed it back to at the end of the body and it started working. Thanks mate. But cant think through why is it this way?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue, it turns out that I had accidentally deleted the `<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>` from my `layout.html.eex` file. Adding it back fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For later versions of Phoenix, if you view the app.js file within `priv/static/js/app.js` you'll notice a comment that references a link to a raw github js file.  This small snippet of Javascript contains important code to ensure that the `delete` link helpers actually work correctly.