# Elixir phoenix Logout link does not work

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following Logout link in my app, but when i click on it, it does not do anything.

```html
<li class="nav-item">
  <%= link "Logout", to: session_path(@conn, :delete), method: :delete, class: "nav-link" %>
</li>
```

The html element the above code generates is

```html
<li class="nav-item">
  <form action="/logout" class="link" method="post">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete">
    <input name="_csrf_token" type="hidden" value="GiA4JANYN10+JQhfUgIEARxZCRIEAAAUijC25v5Kj8j7KI6qrOtv==">
    <a data-submit="parent" href="#">Logout</a>
  </form>
</li>
```

Does anyone see anything obviously wrong here that the logout link would not do anything when clicked?

brunch-config.js

```js
javascripts: {
 joinTo: {
   "js/app.js": /^(web\/static\/js)/,
   "js/jquery-ujs.js.js": ["web/static/vendor/js/jquery-ujs.js.js"],
   "js/jquery.js": ["web/static/vendor/js/jquery.js"]
 },
 ...
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34272706/delete-link-not-working-phoenix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the code that is responsible for handling such cases is in the `phoenix_html` package's js file so you need to make sure you have added this package to `mix` and have the following line in your app.js file uncommented:

`import "deps/phoenix_html/web/static/js/phoenix_html"`

Comment: it's not working for me, the logout still has # value on href

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happened due to missing npm dependencies.

In phoenix.server logs I've noticed that app.js wasn't built due to absence of babel-preset-2015 and then babel-preset-2016.

```
npm i --save-dev babel-preset-2015 babel-preset-2016
```

Answer (score -1):

One possible workaround is to do a GET request instead of a DELETE request:

Your html.eex code:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <%= link "Logout", to: session_path(@conn, :delete), class: "nav-link" %>
</li>
```

An example router.ex:

```
resources "/sessions", SessionController, only: [:new, :create]
get "/sessions", SessionController, :delete
```

Comment: While this will work, it's not recommended to use this approach. Session is an entity and as such can be created, updated, viewed or destroyed. For these actions HTML has different actions, by which browser and responding server knows (and therefore can do some checks) about what are trying to click on just by checking type of a request. GET request are generally not checked, while others have to have for example proper csrf token to avoid XSS scripts.