# Bootstrap styled button not being applied to Phoenix delete link

Tags: npm, elixir, phoenix-framework, brunch

- Elixir version: 1.3.2
- Phoenix version: 1.2.1
- NodeJS version: 4.4.6
- NPM version: 3.10.6
- Brunch version: 2.7.4
- Operating system: Mac OSX

I am trying to create what suppose to be a simple link using Phoenix's [`link` helper function](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Link.html).

```
<li><%= link "Logout", to: session_path(@conn, :delete, user), method: :delete %></li>
```

renders

```
<form action="/logout/1" class="link" method="post">
  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete">
  <input name="_csrf_token" type="hidden" value="VhxiLApJElIS...removed for clarity">
  <a data-submit="parent" href="#" rel="nofollow">Logout</a>
</form>
```

The button works fine and the user logs out but the styling of the button isn't being applied. See below:

[image: bootstrap button]

The "logout" button should be aligned with and contain hover effects like the "Home" button . **What is removing the styling of the logout button?**

When a user logs out the styling returns:

[image: navigation bar buttons]

Here are other related issues on the delete link functionality.

- [Delete link not working phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34272706/delete-link-not-working-phoenix)
- https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/1204
- https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/1408
- https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/1319

Here's what I've tried based on the other issues I've found:

- run `brunch build`- compilation succeeds
- change the `link` function to `button`

Hopefully this is enough information to get some input.

Answer (score 0):

The delete links do create a form and this is expected. If you look at what the generators create, its something like below:

```
<%= link "Delete", to: schedule_path(@conn, :delete, schedule), method: :delete, data: [confirm: "Are you sure?"], class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs" %>
```

You cannot call a delete or post method from a anchor directly, so Phoenix makes a form for you.  It's a convenience feature, but can be confusing at first.  So if the form is not working the problem may be in your controller not with the form itself.

Comment: Hey @dds1024 so I diverted a bit as I was asking the question and forgot to mention that the link does indeed work but the styling of the button is off. See the updates above. Thank you.

Comment: Alright, sorry thats a completely different question. Your either going to have to write some CSS to override the form, or go a different route and actually use a link that is intercepted with javascript and submitted with ajax.  Similar from Rails: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25309599/using-bootstrap-icons-with-button-to-delete-in-rails-3  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429066/twitter-bootstrap-modal-rails-delete-button-not-working